# Get sum of multiple input fields inside jquery each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have multiple dropzone elements in which previews of an uploaded image are shown. Inside those previews I added input fields with a `+` and `-` button next to it by clicking you can add or substract the value of that input field. This works fine, but now I need to get the sum of all input fields (only in that dropzone, so only in that iteration of the `each` function.

On Stack Overflow I found a function that I tweaked a bit to get the following code:

```
$plusbtn.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
    $input.val(currentValue + 1);

    $preview.each(function(){
        currentValue += +$input.val();
    });
    console.log(currentValue);
});
```

`currentValue` shows a number in the console increased by `2` every time I click the `+` button instead of the total sum. For example `1-3-5-7-9-11`.

This is the entire code inside the each function.

```
$('.dropzone').each(function(index, element){
    let $el = $(element);
    let $maxfiles = $el.attr('maxfiles');
    let $inputquantity = $el.find('input').val();
    let uploaded_preview = $('.hiddendiv').html();
    let $thisdropzone = $el;

    $el.dropzone({
        paramName: 'postedFile',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictDefaultMessage: '<i class="fas fa-file-upload uploadicon"></i> <span class="uploadtxt">Upload je bestand(en)</span>',
        dictRemoveFile: 'Verwijder',
        dictCancelUpload: 'Annuleren',
        dictInvalidFileType: 'Dit type bestand is niet toegestaan',
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation: 'Weet je zeker dat je het uploaden wilt annuleren?',
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Maximale aantal bestanden overschreden',
        maxFiles: $maxfiles,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .tif, .tiff',
        thumbnailWidth: '205',
        thumbnailHeight: '140',
        thumbnailMethod: 'crop',
        previewTemplate: uploaded_preview,
        processing: function (file) {

        },
        // File contains dropzone file object, response contains ajax response from php file
        success: function (file, response) {
            // alert('test');
            let file_meta = JSON.parse(response);
            let $preview = $(file.previewElement);
            let $plusbtn = $preview.find('#plusupload');
            let $minbtn = $preview.find('#minupload');
            let $input = $preview.find('.fileinput');

            // Input plus min
            $plusbtn.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
                $input.val(currentValue + 1);

                $preview.each(function(){
                    currentValue += +$input.val();
                });
                console.log(currentValue);
            });

            $minbtn.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
                $input.val(currentValue - 1);

                $input.each(function(){
                    currentValue += -$(this).val();
                });
            });

            if(file_meta[0].status == 'success'){

            }else if(file_meta[0].status == 'error'){
                $preview.find('.vrijgevenbtn').show();
                $preview.find('.foutformaat').show();
            }
            $preview.find('.bestandnaam').text('Bestandsnaam: ' + file_meta[0].filename);
            $preview.find('.resolutie').text('Resolutie: ' + file_meta[0].dpi + ' DPI');
            $preview.find('.formaat').text('Formaat: ' + file_meta[0].heightcm + ' x ' + file_meta[0].widthcm + 'cm');
        },
    })
});
```

How can I get the sum of all input fields per `each` iteration?

Here is a snippet:

```js
let counter = 0;
$('.dropzone').each(function(index, element){
    let $el = $(element);
    let $maxfiles = $el.attr('maxfiles');
    let $inputquantity = $el.find('input').val();
    let uploaded_preview = $('.hiddendiv').html();
    let $thisdropzone = $el;
    
    $el.dropzone({
        paramName: 'postedFile',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictDefaultMessage: '<i class="fas fa-file-upload uploadicon"></i> <span class="uploadtxt">Upload je bestand(en)</span>',
        dictRemoveFile: 'Verwijder',
        dictCancelUpload: 'Annuleren',
        dictInvalidFileType: 'Dit type bestand is niet toegestaan',
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation: 'Weet je zeker dat je het uploaden wilt annuleren?',
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: 'Maximale aantal bestanden overschreden',
        maxFiles: $maxfiles,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .tif, .tiff',
        thumbnailWidth: '205',
        thumbnailHeight: '140',
        thumbnailMethod: 'crop',
        previewTemplate: uploaded_preview,
        processing: function (file) {

        },
        // File contains dropzone file object, response contains ajax response from php file
        error: function (file, response) {
            
            counter++;
            console.log('Option ' + counter);
            response = '[{"status":"error","filename":"instablok'+counter+'.jpg","filesize":22822,"tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpI6ov6y","height":172,"width":565,"heightcm":"6'+counter+',07","widthcm":"19'+counter+',93","tifwidth":null,"dpi":"72"}]';

let file_meta = JSON.parse(response);
        let $preview = $(file.previewElement);
        let $plusbtn = $preview.find('#plusupload');
        let $minbtn = $preview.find('#minupload');
        let $input = $preview.find('.fileinput');

        // Input plus min
        $plusbtn.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
            let sum = 0;
            $input.val(currentValue + 1);

            $preview.each(function(){
                currentValue += +parseInt($input.val());
            });
            console.log(currentValue);
        });

        $minbtn.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
            $input.val(currentValue - 1);

            $input.each(function(){
                currentValue += +$(this).val();
            });
        });
            

            if(file_meta[0].status == 'success'){

            }else if(file_meta[0].status == 'error'){
                $preview.find('.vrijgevenbtn').show();
                $preview.find('.foutformaat').show();
            }
            $preview.find('.bestandnaam').text('Bestandsnaam: ' + file_meta[0].filename);
            $preview.find('.resolutie').text('Resolutie: ' + file_meta[0].dpi + ' DPI');
            $preview.find('.formaat').text('Formaat: ' + file_meta[0].heightcm + ' x ' + file_meta[0].widthcm + 'cm');
        },
    })
});
```

```css
.hiddendiv {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Disable auto discover for all elements:
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">

<table class="table upload-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="plantmore-product-thumbnail uploadimg" width="100">
            <a href=""><img src="assets/images/noimg.jpg" alt=""></a>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-name" width="200">
            <div class="prodinfocheckout">
               <a class="prodname" href="">
               Monomeer
               </a>
               <span id="togglespecscheckout" class="prodspecscheckout noselect">
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> Specificaties
               </span>
               <div class="togglespecscheckout">
                  Hoogte : 20cm
                  <br>
                  Breedte : 20cm
                  <br>
                  uploaden : 1
                  <br>
                  Lijmlaag : Wit
                  <br>
                  Laminaat : Anti-slip laminaat
                  <br>
                  Afwerking : Contoursnijden
                  <br>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="190">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">
            Benodigd formaat:<br>
            <span class="benodigd">20 x 20cm</span>
            </span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="185">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Benodigde aantal<br> bestanden: <span class="benodigd">10</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Bestanden <br>toegewezen: <span class="benodigd">0 / 10</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" valign="top">
            <button class="uploadbutton btn yellowbtn dz-clickable">Bestand(en) uploaden</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="newrow">
         <td colspan="6">
            <form action="upload/uploaden.php" class="dropzone dropzoneform dz-clickable" maxfiles="10" id="dropzone1">
               <input type="hidden" value="Monomeer" name="productnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="Twan" name="klantnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="20" name="hoogte">
               <input type="hidden" value="20" name="breedte">
               <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span><i class="fas fa-file-upload uploadicon"></i> <span class="uploadtxt">Upload je bestand(en)</span></span></div>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="plantmore-product-thumbnail uploadimg" width="100">
            <a href=""><img src="assets/images/noimg.jpg" alt=""></a>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-name" width="200">
            <div class="prodinfocheckout">
               <a class="prodname" href="">
               Monomeer
               </a>
               <span id="togglespecscheckout" class="prodspecscheckout noselect">
               <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> Specificaties
               </span>
               <div class="togglespecscheckout">
                  Hoogte : 90cm
                  <br>
                  Breedte : 90cm
                  <br>
                  uploaden : 1
                  <br>
                  Lijmlaag : Wit
                  <br>
                  Laminaat : Anti-slip laminaat
                  <br>
                  Afwerking : Contoursnijden
                  <br>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="190">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">
            Benodigd formaat:<br>
            <span class="benodigd">90 x 90cm</span>
            </span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" width="185">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Benodigde aantal<br> bestanden: <span class="benodigd">1</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity">
            <span class="centervertical">
            <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="amount">Bestanden <br>toegewezen: <span class="benodigd">0 / 1</span></span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="plantmore-product-quantity" valign="top">
            <button class="uploadbutton btn yellowbtn dz-clickable">Bestand(en) uploaden</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="newrow">
         <td colspan="6">
            <form action="upload/uploaden.php" class="dropzone dropzoneform dz-clickable" maxfiles="1" id="dropzone4">
               <input type="hidden" value="Monomeer" name="productnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="Twan" name="klantnaam">
               <input type="hidden" value="90" name="hoogte">
               <input type="hidden" value="90" name="breedte">
               <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span><i class="fas fa-file-upload uploadicon"></i> <span class="uploadtxt">Upload je bestand(en)</span></span></div>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>


  <div class="hiddendiv">

    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
          <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
          <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
            <span class="infoline">
                <span class="infospan bestandnaam">Bestandnaam:</span>
                <!-- <i class="fas fa-times-circle afgekeurd"></i> -->
            </span>
      <span class="infoline">
                <span class="infospan resolutie">Resolutie:</span>
                <!-- <i class="fas fa-check-circle goedgekeurd"></i> -->
            </span>
      <span class="infoline">
                <span class="infospan formaat">Formaat:</span>
                <!-- <i class="fas fa-times-circle afgekeurd"></i> -->
            </span>
            <div class="foutformaat">
                <span>Bestand heeft niet het benodigde formaat.</span>
                <span class="uploadinfobox">
                    <button class="infotooltip tooltipupload" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum">
                        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
      <button class="yellowbtn btn vrijgevenbtn" type="button">Bestand vrijgeven</button>
            <hr class="uploadline">
            <span class="toewijzen">Aantal</span>
      <div class="uploadcontent">
        <input type="number" value="0" min="0" class="fileinput">
   <button class="plusminupload" id="minupload">−</button>
                                                                <button class="plusminupload" id="plusupload">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look a this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k5ut29os/

I added a variable in the dropzone's foreach to hold the total, and a function to update it.

```
let this_dropzone_sum = 0;
function updateTotal(){
    this_dropzone_sum = 0;
    $el.find('.uploadcontent input').each( function(){
        this_dropzone_sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
}
```

Then I called the function in the two buttons (plus/minus)

```
$plusbtn.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let currentValue = parseInt($input.val());
    let sum = 0;

    // update input
    $input.val(currentValue + 1);

    updateTotal();
    console.log(this_dropzone_sum);

});
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Just to add to the answer of @pietro : Your preview.each doesn't do anything with the value of the input - you just add the current input value again for each input.

Comment: @Pietro I don't see the total being updated in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: It's in the console. I'll update the fiddle to write into that span (I used it for a moment, but I forgot to remove it)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think I understand your meaning you want to know hoy many inputs fields are in the page?

if so you can do by document.querySelectorAll('input').length

Comment: You want to get the sum of the value of the inputs of so... do somthing like this:
`inputs.map((obj)=> obj.value).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)`